# Install OS X recovery mode. Can't log in

Tags: macos, install, recovery, apple-store, authentication

Dusting off an old iMac and it was hanging at 50% progress bar during start up.  Since I don't need anything on it I'm trying to reformat.

I've booted into recovery mode and erased the drive.  Then selected to install new OS.  Chose the drive (it's also showing a locked recovery drive).  By then it asks me to log into Apple Store.  I do and it's saying wrong password.  But then my phone asks for permission for login with my account.  I approve and it still doesn't let me in on the iMac.  Phone is giving an auth code but no where to enter it on iMac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the operating system of the recovery partition is probably lower than 10.11.0.

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915) you have to append the auth code to the password then:

> What if I use two-factor authentication on a device running older software?
>   If you use two-factor authentication with devices running older OS versions, you might be asked to add your six-digit verification code to the end of your password when signing in. Get your verification code from a trusted device running iOS 9 and later or OS X El Capitan and later, or have it sent to your trusted phone number. Then type your password followed by the six-digit verification code directly into the password field.